# snowflake string replace javascript udf

Tags: javascript, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Trying to utilize Javascript's [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function in Snowflake, because apparently Snowflake's `regex_replace` function lacks certain features such ast (forward/backward) look arounds.

Here is my Javascript UDF attempt:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION REXP_REPLACE_ME(subject TEXT, pattern TEXT, replacement TEXT)
  RETURNS string
  LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
  AS
  $$
    const p = SUBJECT;
    const regex = PATTERN;
    return p.replace(regex, REPLACEMENT);
  $$
  ;
```

However, when I try to execute using the example provided in the `string.prototype.replace()` documentation linked above.  I'm not getting the expected result:

```
SELECT REXP_REPLACE_ME('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy ferret. If the dog reacted, was it really lazy?', '/Dog/i', 'cat')

//expected output: 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy ferret. If the cat reacted, was it really lazy?'
//actual output: 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy ferret. If the dog reacted, was it really lazy?'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because in Javascript the regex is not string lateral, it is it's own thing.

```
> a = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy ferret. If the dog reacted, was it really lazy?';
'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy ferret. If the dog reacted, was it really lazy?'
> b = a.replace('/Dog/i', 'cat');
'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy ferret. If the dog reacted, was it really lazy?'
> b = a.replace(/Dog/i, 'cat');
'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy ferret. If the cat reacted, was it really lazy?'
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working version for those who come across this in the future:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION REXP_REPLACE_ME(subject TEXT, pattern TEXT, replacement TEXT)
  RETURNS string
  LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
  AS
  $$
  
    const p = SUBJECT;
    let regex = new RegExp(PATTERN, 'i') 
    return p.replace(regex, REPLACEMENT);
  $$
  ;
```